# Проблема с кодировкой при работе с QtSql и postgresql на Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, postgresql, locale

Подключаюсь к Postgres через QtSql. В БД стоит кодировка cp1251. Пробовал менять локали с помощью setlocale в коде. Также пробовал менять кодривки в самой БД. Результат один и тот же - кракозябры.

Данные приходят в не той кодировке:

```
name info // имя колонок
РђСЂРєС‚СѓСЂ РЇСЂРєР°СЏ Р·РІРµР·РґР° // данные
Арктур Яркая звезда // ожидаемые данные
```

[скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm5NX.png)

Comment: А приложение консольное?

Comment: приветденный пример - это utf-8->cp1251.Похоже, "стоит кодировка" означает "выбрана кодировка для отображения".

Comment: Отдельно создал консольный экзешник. Консольный вывод менять пробовал.
У меня не приложение, а либа. 
Вывод запроса в БД обрабатывается внутри нее. В логи такие же кракозябры пишутся. Перепробовал кучу советов, которые на стэке нашел. 
Возможно, кто-то сталкивался. Потому что проблема, по всей видимости где-то на поверхности, не могу понять где.

Comment: без примера кода как гадать?